# Java Fee Form Project Run through commandLine

Tags: java

I have Java application & it contain custom ant build script for running application. I want to know about how to run the particular Java file using command line

My Project Structure:

```
  MyProjectDemo  -  ant build script
       src
          example
             Test.java
             TestExample.java
              .....
```

This project import other project library also.

I want to run Test.java file using commandLine.

When I run using `javac Test.java` , it throw an error.

I have tried several way , but couldn't fixed this. I an using Ubuntu OS.

Please anyone help this.

Comment: What is the error? Are you trying to build or run the file from the command line?

Comment: Yes.`pir@1it-seswipe:~/Projects/Demo/cebpp/src/demo/excises/inf_03$ javac -d . Test.java 
pir@1it-seswipe:~/Projects/Demo/cebpp/src/demo/excises/inf_03$ java Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
pir@1it-seswipe:~/Projects/Demo/cebpp/src/demo/excises/inf_03$ `  This is an error